# What is the most efficient between Timer and managing my own thread?

Tags: c#

I have an object and I want to delay an operation. I made two different implementation for this. The first one uses System.Threading.Timer to delay my operation while the second one uses a static thread and an expiration date. Personnaly, I prefer the first method, but I was wandering if there's any overhead for using a Timer rather than a managed Thread.

First implementation :

```
class ThingWithDelayedClose
{
    private Action<ThingWithDelayedClose> _closeCallback;

    public ThingWithDelayedClose(string key, Action<ThingWithDelayedClose> closeCallback)
    {
        this.Key = key;

        _closeCallback = closeCallback;

        Console.WriteLine("Object created: " + this.Key);
    }

    public string Key { get; private set; }

    public void RequestClose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Close requested: " + this.Key);

        dynamic state = new ExpandoObject();

        state.Timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.TimerCallback), state, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(dynamic state)
    {
        using ((Timer)state.Timer)
        {
            _closeCallback(this);

            Console.WriteLine("Object closed: " + this.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Second implementation :

```
class ThingWithDelayedClose
{
    static List<ThingWithDelayedClose> s_instances;

    static ThingWithDelayedClose()
    {
        s_instances = new List<ThingWithDelayedClose>();

        new Thread(() =>
            {
                // I know that I would need to change this in a real world app
                while (true)
                {
                    lock (s_instances)
                    {
                        var now = DateTime.Now;
                        var removeList = new List<ThingWithDelayedClose>();

                        foreach (var instance in s_instances)
                        {
                            if (instance._closedTime <= now)
                            {
                                instance.Close();

                                removeList.Add(instance);
                            }
                        }

                        removeList.ForEach(p => s_instances.Remove(p));
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }).Start();
    }

    private DateTime _closedTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
    private Action<ThingWithDelayedClose> _closeCallback;

    public ThingWithDelayedClose(string key, Action<ThingWithDelayedClose> closeCallback)
    {
        this.Key = key;

        _closeCallback = closeCallback;

        Console.WriteLine("Object created: " + this.Key);

        lock (s_instances)
        {
            s_instances.Add(this);
        }
    }

    public string Key { get; private set; }

    public void RequestClose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Close requested: " + this.Key);

        _closedTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0d));
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        _closeCallback(this);

        Console.WriteLine("Object closed: " + this.Key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a timer is substantially cheaper than spinning up a new thread.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you can probably make it even faster (and simpler and safer) by using one of the built-in synchronization primitives in `System.Threading`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Timer is cheaper as long as you're talking about only one thread but the 2nd implementation is better if you have more then one operation because each Timer.Elapsed is actually run on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of a Timer is much lower than the overhead of a Thread. Creating (and switching to and from) a Thread takes synchronization, which is - especially in the case of multiple processors - quite an expensive operation.

Also, consider that your threaded example calls back in a separate thread than the main thread, which requires all your clients to be thread aware too.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are expensive to create and can be somewhat expensive to keep.  If one has a job to perform which can be described in terms of a single method which enters, does some stuff, and exits fairly quickly, creating a whole new thread, performing a little work with it, and then abandoning it is likely to be wasteful.  In many cases, it would be more efficient to keep the thread around for a little while, to see if a thread is needed for some other quick job; if such a need arises, the job can be handled by that first thread, without having to create a new one.  The .net Framework provides a system, called the threadpool, for automatically dispatching short jobs using a moderate number of reusable threads.  Note that the number of threads that will be simultaneously dispatched by the threadpool is limited; if jobs are submitted faster than they are completed, later jobs will have to wait until earlier jobs are completed.  For this reason, long-running jobs, especially ones that will involve a lot of "waiting", should not use the threadpool.

If one has a job to perform which will take a long time to complete, it's possible to create a new thread and run the job there.  This can be much better than the threadpool, especially if the job will entail a lot of waiting.  On the other hand, every live thread, even one that's simply "waiting", will tie up a significant quantity of memory that could otherwise be used for other things.  In some cases, the simplicity of using a new thread may be worth the cost.  On the other hand, there are many scenarios that can be handled more cheaply in other ways, such as by using a timer.

Effectively, a timer object requests that once enough time has elapsed, either a form's thread (in the case of the Forms timer) or a threadpool thread (for the system timer) should be run a specified piece of code.  If one can easily encapsulate within an object all the information which the code will need, a timer is much cheaper than a thread.  The biggest place a thread can be helpful is when one would have to simulate a complicated sequence of events, and making all necessary all the information necessary for timers and other such objects to perform their required operations would be far more complicated and tedious than simply using "straight-line" code within a single thread to perform the same job.